# torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder() unable to load image files

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I have tested this file path using PIL and Image.open(), however, when using torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder() I am consistently receiving the error "[Errno 20] Not a directory". I have pasted my code below and would love help trouble shooting where I may be going wrong.

````
image_size = (64,64)
stats = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)

transform_ds = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(image_size),
#                                    transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=2),
#                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                                   transforms.Normalize(*stats)
                                   ])

train_ds = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root="/Users/____/Desktop/stylegan/images",
                                     transform=transform_ds)

train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=3, pin_memory=True)
print(len(train_ds))```

full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/___/Desktop/stylegan/stylegan.py", line 30, in <module>
    train_ds = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='/Users/___/Desktop/stylegan/images/anonym.4.jpg',
  File "/Users/___/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 310, in __init__
    super(ImageFolder, self).__init__(root, loader, IMG_EXTENSIONS if is_valid_file is None else None,
  File "/Users/___/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 145, in __init__
    classes, class_to_idx = self.find_classes(self.root)
  File "/Users/___/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 221, in find_classes
    return find_classes(directory)
  File "/Users/___/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 40, in find_classes
    classes = sorted(entry.name for entry in os.scandir(directory) if entry.is_dir())
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/___/Desktop/stylegan/images/anonym.4.jpg'
````

Comment: Can you please provide the full traceback? Also, provide the code where you use PIL too.

Comment: Just posted the full traceback. My PIL code was pretty simple ```img = Image.open(path)

Comment: I asked for that just to make sure you were using exactly the same path. In most cases, people aren't.

Comment: Ahh I see. Yes it was the same path I have double checked.

Answer (score 0):

The full traceback reveals that:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/___/Desktop/stylegan/stylegan.py", line 30, in <module>
    train_ds = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='/Users/___/Desktop/stylegan/images/anonym.4.jpg'
```

you are actually passing `root='/Users/___/Desktop/stylegan/images/anonym.4.jpg'`, which is a path to an image. The code you provided is **not** the code you are actually running. Maybe you forgot to save/sync or you're running in something like IPython and forgot to re-run some cell?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! I actually attempted to write the path to an image inside of the file after posting and accidentally copied that traceback instead. Even still I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @aidan.goetzinger I'd say that showing that this path is valid by loading an image using PIL as you suggested you did just before `train_ds = ` line would be great to help you.